# Adding patches to numpy array opened in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to draw boxes on an image opened from an array in matplotlib. One way I have found to draw boxes is by using [`add_patch`](http://matthiaseisen.com/pp/patterns/p0203/), but I can't find the way to use it on an image loaded from an array.

This code

```
arr = np.random.rand(400,400)
fig = plt.imshow(arr)
fig.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((100, 100), 100, 100, fill=False))
```

produces the error: AttributeError: 'AxesImage' object has no attribute 'add_patch'

Comment: `imshow` returns an `AxisImage` not a `Figure`. A `Figure` object does not have an `add_patch` method, `Axes` objects do. Apparently `AxisImage` doesn't inherit from `AxisBase` however. You can get the axes of an `AxisImage` through the `axes` property. eg `plt.imshow(arr).axes`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add your patch to the matplotlib Axes :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.rand(400,400)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

ax.imshow(arr)
rect = patches.Rectangle((100, 100), 100, 100, fill=False)
ax.add_patch(rect)
plt.show()
```